# HTTP base metatag and path on apache

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, path, radix

We have a fantastic design plugin stored on the (shared) server in a path like

```
/design/plungins/fantastic/
```

The plugin itself has dozens of files and many sub-directories.

If in the HTML header section of the web page we set something like

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/design/plungins/fantastic/" target="_self">
```

everything works like a charm.

Recently, we started adding sub-domains:

```
http://www.sub1.example.com/
http://www.sub2.example.com/
http://www.sub3.example.com/
```

so in the HTML header section of each sub-domain we now need to include the full path to the plugin files to have them found, like that:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/design/plungins/fantastic/icons.css"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/design/plungins/fantastic/fonts.css">
```

and these .css files are indeed found and included.

The problem is that some of the .css have inside their code something like that:

```
src:url('../fonts/great-font.eot?v=5.1');
```

Due to the **../** in the .css the fonts are not found, of course.

We don't know how to solve this problem. We refuse to duplicate the plugin code to each sub-domain we create. We refuse to edit the css, too. Perhaps symbolic links would do the job, but we don't know the tech quite well.

Comment: copy the fonts folder into --  design/plungins/fantastic/ -- and amend the src url to--  src:url('fonts/great-font.eot?v=5.1');

Answer (score 0):

If you refuse to copy the plugin, the only solution to mee seems to use full paths. This is done by replacing

```
src:url('../fonts/great-font.eot?v=5.1');
```

with

```
src:url('http://www.example.com/design/plungins/fonts/great-font.eot?v=5.1');
```

Like you did for the stylesheets.

Hope t helps. If it does, +1.

Comment: Thank you Vann, but this would mean editing a few hundred (yes) entries in the minified .css. We are still looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: You could use an advanced text editor's function find-replace. That it is how I do such edits.